# Flutter Dividers not showing up

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Codes:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: const [
    const Divider(color: Colors.black, thickness: 1, indent: 50, height: 25,),
    const SizedBox(width: 10),
    const Divider(color: Colors.black, thickness: 1, indent: 50, height: 25,),
    const SizedBox(width: 10),
    const Divider(color: Colors.black, thickness: 1, indent: 50, height: 25,),
    const SizedBox(width: 10),
    const Divider(color: Colors.black, thickness: 1, indent: 50, height: 25,),
  ],
),
```

As you can see, there are 4 Dividers. But they do not appear in practice. They take up space but are not visible. Why could this be? How can I solve it?

I tryed:

```
Row(
  children:  [
    VerticalDivider(color: Colors.black, thickness: 1, indent: 50, width: 25,),
    SizedBox(width: 10),
    VerticalDivider(color: Colors.red, thickness: 1, indent: 50, width: 25,),
    SizedBox(width: 10),
    VerticalDivider(color: Colors.red, thickness: 1, indent: 50, width: 25,),
    SizedBox(width: 10),
    VerticalDivider(color: Colors.black, thickness: 1, indent: 50, width: 20,),
  ],
),
```

and

```
VerticalDivider(color: Colors.black, thickness: 1, indent: 50, width: 25,),
SizedBox(width: 10),
VerticalDivider(color: Colors.red, thickness: 1, indent: 50, width: 25,),
SizedBox(width: 10),
VerticalDivider(color: Colors.red, thickness: 1, indent: 50, width: 25,),
SizedBox(width: 10),
VerticalDivider(color: Colors.black, thickness: 1, indent: 50, width: 20,),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 100,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  thickness: 10,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  thickness: 10,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  thickness: 10,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  thickness: 10,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[[image: preview]

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't show up. The problem persists.

Comment: Edited my answer please check

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but I think you misunderstood me. I want these Dividers horizontally side by side. Not vertically.

Comment: Edited my answer again.. Please check

Answer (score 1):

For row, you mostly likely want `VerticalDivider` instead of `Divider`. and height depend on parent size.

```dart
VerticalDivider(
  color: Colors.black,
  thickness: 44,
  indent: 50,
),
```

More about [`VerticalDivider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/VerticalDivider-class.html)

As for the UI you are seeking, you can use `Container` with padding widget.

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.black,
    width: 44,
    height: 25,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't show up. The problem persists.

Comment: what is the parent widget, Can you include full widget with scaffold that will reproduce the same issue  ?

Comment: I've added all my codes to the thread.

Comment: Can you include an image that are you trying to archive?

Comment: Hello. I solved the problem with `SizedBox`. Thank you.